# Is there a chance to store a data in switching activity

Tags: android, android-activity

considering I have 3 activities
1st activity is main activity and it contains 2 buttons..one for going to second activity and another for third activity 
if I send a data form activity 2 to activity 3 and if I get back to activity 1 and go to activity 3...the previously given data is being deleted
I want to store the previously given data in activity 3

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really "store" data in activities. They are transient. They come and go. You can store data in `SharedPreferences` or in an SQLite database or in a file. If you just have a small amount of data, you can keep it in memory and then send it to each `Activity` when you launch the `Activity` by putting it in an "extra" in the `Intent`. Or you can use a "global" variable (ie: `public static` in Java) which will allow access from all activities.

There are many, many tutorials and discussions about how to store data on Android. Search a bit and I'm sure you will find something useful.